# Clean database on application startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, signalr, c#-8.0

I've adapted an approach of mapping `signalr` connections to users to my `aspnet core 3.0` app.
The approach I'm referring to is outlined in [Mapping SignalR Users to Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#permanent-external-storage), section `Permanent, external storage`. I know that this article was written for a different version of Asp.Net but it came in handy.

**This is the code of the Hub:**

```cs
public class SomeHub : Hub
{
    private readonly UserManager _userManager;
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

    protected BaseHub(UserManager userManager, AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetMe();
        user.Connections.Add(new Connection { ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId });
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception ex)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetMe();
        if (await _dbContext.Connections.FindAsync(Context.ConnectionId) is {} connection)
        {
            user.Connections.Remove(connection);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(ex);
    }
}
```

## Question

If I teardown my application, `Connection` database entries will remain in my database, because the `OnDisconnectedAsync` method was not called.

**Is there a possibility to remove those entries once the application starts?**

Comment: That document is for the old ASP.NET SignalR, not ASP.NET Core SignalR. There's a very strong warning in a colored panel at the top of the article saying: `This documentation isn't for the latest version of SignalR. Take a look at ASP.NET Core SignalR.`

Comment: This is true, please see the updated version of the question. Still there seems to be no matching article for the newest version. At least I did not find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add the following code inside the `Configure` method of the `Startup` class after calling `AddDbContext`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>([...]);

    using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
    using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    using (var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>())
    {
        context.Connections.RemoveRange(context.Connections);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: If you don't want persistent connections, why use a database? Unless you want to deploy to a farm?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos With signalr a single physical user is able to connect to the same hub using multiple devices, tabs, and browsers. Also the stored connections help me adding and removing the user to signalr groups, when it is requested.

Answer (score 0):

On .net 6

*program.cs*

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ClassName>();
...
var app = builder.Build();
var cleanconnections = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ClassName>();
cleanconnections.DoStuff();
```